# Three.js gui disappearing in background behind reloaded textures

Tags: javascript, user-interface, graphics, three.js

So I'm guessing this is normal behavior, but I wanted to ask to make sure, and to figure out how to fix this problem.

In my mapping app, I have a plane that gets pre-loaded with some textures, and it creates a gui, like the one here:

[GUI](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/GUI.html)

However in reality, the program creates a bunch of "layers" each with their own textures and places them in the same spot.  One layer corresponds to one zoom level.  So when the user zooms in a certain amount, it loops through the current visible layer and makes those meshes invisible, while making the new ones for the next zoom level visible.

The problem I'm having is that my GUI gets pushed to the background, behind the textures.  How do I keep the GUI in front?

[image]

**I also cannot click on anything on the GUI.  I've inspected the html, and there's nothing indicative of causing this.  I even changed the *z-index* to be sure and it had no effect.**

**I've turned off all the textures, still having this problem.  The strange part is, the working GUI example I linked above has html that looks exactly like mine. No clue what this could be**

Comment: can you put your code to jsfiddle?

Comment: sorry, this question can be closed.  turned out to be a z-index property on a parent element I wasn't checking.